# Extending network with switch after extender

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I want to expand my home internet network.
The way i want to do this is by using a switch, this switch would be placed after an extender.
An overview of my network: Modem -> router -> (devices &) extender.
The thing is that i need to connect both a tv box and my tv with an ethernet cable, and since the modem and router are pretty far away i want to use a switch. I already have my tv box connected directly from the extender, but the extender only has one ethernet output, so that's where the switch comes in.

I only want to know if this is possible.
Thanks in forward.

Comment: Yes; It's possible.

Comment: Depending on the lengths of the cabling, it's absolutely possible.